# Converting to Datum type in PostgreSQL

Tags: c, postgresql

I see that the `fetchfunc` is used to access the column values of the sample rows fetched for statistics collection. The function returns a `Datum`. Individually when we know of the datatype, we can use the functions like `Float8GetDatum` `Int16GetDatum` and so on to convert to `Datum` type.

My problem is:

`Input` : a column in a relation and a valid value that the column can take.

I have to find the datatype of the column and based on that, I need to use the right function to convert the given input value to the Datum value to be stored internally.

I am very confused on how to go about this in postgreSQL.

Comment: Which programming language are you talking about?

Comment: Assuming you are using libpq on C -- why do you want to do that? You can only supply your queries' parameters in their string (input representation) format (not `Datum`): http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-exec.html -- But if you really want to find out a column's type, you can query the `pg_attribute` system table in `pg_catalog`.

Comment: Ok.. I am writing a function inside the postgreSQL code (C), that needs to do this. So I should be able to  find the column datatype using C.

Comment: Look at how the `json` code does it, or other functions that take `anyelement` arguments.

Comment: Then you want to figure out a parameter's type, not a table column's type. There are some information & examples about this in the docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/xfunc-c.html#AEN54057